# css fill height of screen when window is zoomed 100%

Tags: html, css

How do you fill the height when the website is zoomed 100%? When zoomed out i don't want the element to keep filling the screen. To be more clear, when a user enters the website and the website is zoomed by the default 100% the whole screen should be filled with a color. But when the user scrolls down or zooms the fill should not dynamically change its height.

From comments i edit the code to get a better result, but now there is gaps around the element:

```
header.mainHeader {
    background-color: #282828;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it's because you've got it `position: fixed`, therefore the div is always at the same position, regardless of scrolling. I would remove it and subsequent `left` and `top` declarations. Off the top of my head - if you want the initial size to fill the viewport, you could always try using `100vh` as the `height`.

Comment: When i remove position:fixed i get white gaps around the element..

Comment: It's *possibly* to do with the padding/margin on the `body` or another element. **1)** You could set it/them to `0` or **2)** You could apply `box-sizing: border-box` to the *I think, not sure what your CSS is...* `body`- better still, you can apply it to everything (`*` in CSS )- makes it a lot easier in the long-run. FWIW: Setting `border-box` will let the box-model include measurements content, padding and border, but not the margin. At present, it is likely that you're not using this, and it's not taking the `padding` of your body, or another element into account :)

Comment: FYI - had to delete last comment (couldn't edit it) - had some better information to put, see above

Comment: I added box-sizing:border-box but it does not make any difference, see my edited answer

Comment: That's because you're applying it to only the element itself. You need to apply it to its parent e.g. `body` or `*`

Comment: I did it now, but nothing changed. Instead i added margin 0 to the body and now it looks like i want.

Comment: Cool. Glad to have helped. I'll post an answer for you when I get to a computer

Comment: I've added an answer, below. My apologies with the `border-box` confusion - complete duhh on my part - I've confused it with other similar questions/answers, when setting `width`s of elements and they've ended up with whitespace. Completely irrelevant in this instance, disregard previous comments about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're setting the `position: fixed` of the `.mainHeader` class. This causes the element to always be at the same position in the viewport, regardless of zoom-level or scrolling position.

Remove this `position: fixed`, and its corresponding `top` and `left` properties.

---

You're currently setting the `height` to `100%` of its parent element, so it would always be as big as that.

To set the height using the viewport's (visible page area) height, you can use `vh` units, equivalent to percentage of the viewport height (`vh`) - likewise for `width` and `vw`.

So, to set the height of the element to 100% of the viewport height, you can simply do:

```
height: 100vh;
```

**EDIT** - *NOTE:* the `vh` unit isn't supported by *all* browsers (I've found some, trust me). So I would recommend setting a fallback value, above the `vh` one, to prevent incompatibility. For example:

```
height: 500px; // fallback value if browser doesn't support vh
height: 100vh; // this value overrides the above one, if the browser supports vh
```

---

You might then need to remove `padding` and/or `margin` from the `body` or other elements, if you're seeing whitespace around the element. Have a play about to get the right effect.

For example:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  ... other properties
}
```

---

Please find a JSFiddle of this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/s49p6Laj/

Sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  I fill the viewport!
</div>
<div class="other-stuff">
  // All your other content here...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
// Set the body's margin and padding to 0
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

// Make the container fill the viewport
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
```

Comment: Superb answer! Just a small question, what do i do if i want to center the "I fill the viewport!" text vertically (when window is 100% zoomed)?

Comment: It's a bit long to put in a comment, and not in scope to add to my answer, so here's another question (to save you asking one) that answers this in very good detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css